# change the type of function's variable in js

Tags: javascript

I would like to force a function variable type to be a string

```
function removeFirstCharacter (element) {
        var el = (element).toString();
        return el.slice(1);
    }
```

removeFirstCharacter(0011) -> return '' instead of 011.
I don't know why 0011 is converted to an empty string. My aim is when I enter a number, that number should get converted to string. The code works fine for a string parameter. The case of number is my problem only. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You want to call `removeFirstCharacter("0011")` not `removeFirstCharacter(0011)`

Answer (score 4):

> removeFirstCharacter(0011) -> return '' instead of 011. I don't know why 0011 is converted to an empty string.

A leading zero in a number tells javascript to treat it as octal. So `0011` means 9 in decimal, and thus `removeFirstCharacter(0011)` is really `removeFirstCharacter(9)`. When you turn that into a string you get "9", and when you remove the first character, you get an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Remove () at your element.

```js
function removeFirstCharacter (element) {
        var el = element.toString();
        return el.slice(1);
}

console.log(removeFirstCharacter(123));
console.log(removeFirstCharacter("123"));
```

Comment: but it still fails when I do this: console.log(removeFirstCharacter(0123));

Comment: numbers with zero at the start like 0123 are interpreted as octal in most languages including JS. Converted to decimal, 0123 is 83.

Answer (score 0):

You're providing an input number that isn't decimal, and when it is casted to decimal 0011 is equivalent to 9, as Nicholas stated above. Because of this, you will need to parse all numerical input into decimal as shown in console.log below.

Never allow the input data to be considered a 'number' - it should always remain a string until parsed into an int when calling removeFirstCharacter

```
function removeFirstCharacter (element) {
  return element.toString().slice(1);
}

console.log(removeFirstCharacter(parseInt('0011', 10)));
```